# Parse.Query to exclude items where key's value is between two numbers?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm working with a filtering function in a react native app that uses self hosted Parse as a backend. It normally works very well, but I seem to have struck an issue I can't work myself around.

In our app we have three filters that can be individually put on and off. They're called "low", "medium" and "high".

Parse.Query has limiters such as "lessThanOrEqualTo" and "greaterThanOrEqualTo", but there's no "valueNotBetween" which I'd like to have. Our issue rises when we select "low" and "high" at the same time, since we can set the lessThanOrEqual to value to what corresponds to the low filter and the greaterThanOrEqualTo to high's value, but we cant exclude the medium range values.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: i think it is not possible, I would recommend you to assign a value "high, "medium" or "low" when creating these fields (for example using cloud code)...or you can use `notEqualTo` if you have only few lines...

Answer (score 0):

You can do an `or` query (compound query) like documented [here](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_or) & [here](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/#compound-queries)

```
var queryHigh = new Parse.Query("YourClass");
queryHigh.greaterThanOrEqualTo("key",value);
var queryLow = new Parse.Query("YourClass");
queryLow.lessThanOrEqualTo("key",value);
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(queryHigh, queryLow);
mainQuery.find({
  success: function(results) {
     // results 
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // There was an error.
  }
});
```